# Подставить куки в CURL

Tags: curl, php

Как сюда подставить куки, т.е чтобы я мог в curl поставить свои куки, полученные пре предыдущем запросе:

```
function curl($url, $post = false) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1136.94 Safari/537.4 AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = curl('my.url.com', false);
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $m);
parse_str($m[1], $cookies);
var_dump($cookies);
```

Теперь у вас в `$cookies` куки от последнего запроса, делайте с ними что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

собственно в вашем коде уже подгружаются куки из файла 'cookies.txt':

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
```

если "предыдущий запрос" вы тоже делаете с помощью curl, но не используете преведенную вами функцию, то добавьте туда

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
```

это сохранит куки в файл.

P.S. не забывайте указывать правильный путь к jar файлу. скрипту должна быть разрешена запись в каталог\файл